# Set a variable if it's unitialized

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga, quartus

I'm writing a small VHDL process block and I wanted to assign a value to a variable if it hasn't been set yet. The input has no value at first, so I was wondering if there was something that could set `new_ace` to `'0'` if `ace` is still uninitialized or unknown.

```
entity rules is
    port(
        ace      : in std_logic := '0'; --Tried setting 0 as default
        ace_out  : out std_logic
    );
end rules;

architecture behavior of gA6_rules is
begin
    cards: process(ace)

    variable new_ace : std_logic := '0'; --Tried setting 0 as default
    begin
        if ace = 'U' or ace = 'X' then --Tried checking for unitialized
            new_ace := '0';
        else
            new_ace := ace;
        end if;

        ace_out <= new_ace; --Next input will be this output
    end process;
end behavior;
```

The problem is that when I simulate my design, it shows that `ace_out` is still undefined, even if I try setting it with `:= '0'` or if I use the `if` statement.

Comment: An object always has an initial value. The initial value for type std_logic which has a base type  of std_ulogic will be the leftmost value of std_ulogic which is 'U'.  See the IEEE package std_logic_1164. Also note that conditions evaluating to a metavalue ('U') don't do anything in synthesis. VHDL doesn't do in band signaling. Supply an initial value in the declaration - `variable ace : std_logic := '0';`

Comment: @user1155120 Ok that makes a lot more sense now, but I would still need a way to set the value of ace ONLY when it's not defined yet. So is there any way to check `if ace = metavalue('U')`?

Comment: Can your question cite a specific problem you're trying to address  instead of an abstract? You're otherwise demonstrating a lack of research effort. You can test for 'U' - `if ace = 'U' then`... but it doesn't represent realizable hardware. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.8.2.2 The STD_LOGIC_1164 values "The values 'U', 'X', 'W', and '–' are *metalogical values*; they define the behavior of the model itself rather than the behavior of the hardware being synthesized." In hardware we'd used a flip flop to store an event and use it's value in determining whether the event had occurred or not.

Comment: @user1155120 I'm trying to simulate my design, where one of the inputs is its own output. As a result, I'm trying to initialize the variable to 'get the ball rolling'. I updated my code to show the relevant ports and how I set the outputs.

Comment: You're describing a wire. On top of that your code doesn't analyze. It's missing a context clause, ace can't be initialized with a decimal literal, the architecture shows an entity name that is not in evidence, and there's no signal new_card (shows up in the process sensitivity list). If the input port ace is connected assigning an initial value here will have no effect. That value is only of use when the port is open, in which case the if statement condition will not be evaluated TRUE.